# ¿Cómo hacer capturas de pantalla (screenshot) al contenido de un elemento en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer la captura de pantalla de un `div` en JavaScript?, es decir por ejemplo si tengo un `div` que contiene un mapa y quisiera obtener la captura de pantalla de ese contenido tal y como se muestra tras pulsar una tecla:

- ¿Qué funciones me pueden apoyar a lograrlo?
- ¿Se puede realizar de forma intrínseca?

Comment: ¿Ha intentado algo específicamente? si es así, por favor agregue el código en su pregunta.

Comment: Lo e intentado con la librería html2canvas pero no e tenido exito

Comment: Te sugiero realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], modifica agregando detalles, lo que has investigado o tratado para que obtengas mejores respuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No, no sé de una forma de 'captura de pantalla' de un elemento, pero lo que podrías hacer es dibujar los resultados de la prueba en un elemento canvas y luego utilizar la función **toDataURL** del objeto **HTMLCanvasElement** para obtener datos: URI con los contenidos de la imagen.

```
var c = document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
```

Cuando el usuario hace clic en el botón o hace la acción para "Capturar", haz lo siguiente:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id').toDataURL());
```

Esto abrirá una nueva pestaña o ventana con la 'captura de pantalla', que permite al usuario guardarla. No hay forma de invocar un diálogo de 'guardar como', por lo que esto es lo mejor que puede hacer en mi opinión.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887206/10158153).

Comment: @Luis ¿por qué no es útil este post? Una persona te está dando una respuesta, si no está bien encaminada, deberías indicar dónde está mal o por qué no te sirve. De ese modo el usuario podrá mejorarla y ayudarte mejor. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers).